# XML Deserialization Rules

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I need to deserialize xml file and its structured this way:

```
<NPCs>
   <LabAssistant1>
      <Questions>
         <Question>
            <Type>CheckBox</Type>
            <Points>10</Points>
            <Text>Q1</Text>
            <Answers>
               <Answer>
                  <Correct>False</Correct>
                  <Text>A1</Text>
               </Answer> 
               <Answer>
                  <Correct>True</Correct>
                  <Text>A2</Text>
               </Answer> 
               <Answer>
                  <Correct>False</Correct>
                  <Text>A3</Text>
               </Answer> 
            </Answers>
         </Question>
      </Questions>
   </LabAssistant1>

   <LabAssistant2>
      <Questions>
          ...
      </Questions>
   </LabAssistant2>
</NPCs>
```

So as you can see am having root node NPCs and my goal is to read questions separately by LabAssistant1 name or any tag name in NPCs.

```
String questionsPath = path+"/questions.xml";
XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(questionsPath));

XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xmlRoot.ElementName = npc;

reader.ReadToDescendant(npc);
XmlSerializer se = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Question[]),xmlRoot);

Question[] qs=se.Deserialize(reader) as Question[];
    Console.WriteLine(qs.Length.ToString()); // Always 0
```

Above code should output 2 objects of Question as array, but it doesn't

Here are the classes Question and Answer, anything is wrong with my attached attributes?

```
public class Question
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Text")]
    public String Text { get;  set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Answers")]
    public Answer[] Answers { get;  set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
    public QuestionType Type { get;  set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Points")]
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public Question()
    {

    }
    public Question(String text, Answer[] answers, QuestionType type,int points)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Answers = answers;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Points = points;
    }
}

public class Answer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Text")]
    public String Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Correct")]
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public Answer()
    {

    }
    public Answer(String text, bool correct)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Correct = correct;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Because I thought that the serializer is smart enough, but however i am stuck with what attribute to put on the array of answers in Question?

Comment: They you should say that in your question. Say what you tried; say what the outcome was; say what you want the outcome to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`UnknownElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of `XmlSerializer` to load all the lab assistants into memory, like so:

```
public class LabAssistant
{
    static XmlSerializer listSerializer;

    static LabAssistant()
    {
        // This must be cached to prevent memory & resource leaks.
        // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        listSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Question>), new XmlRootAttribute("Questions"));
    }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public static bool TryDeserializeFromXml(XmlElement element, out string name, out LabAssistant assistant)
    {
        name = element.Name;
        var child = element.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(el => el.Name == "Questions").FirstOrDefault();
        if (child != null)
        {
            var list = child.OuterXml.LoadFromXML<List<Question>>(listSerializer);
            if (list != null)
            {
                assistant = new LabAssistant() { Questions = list };
                return true;
            }
        }
        assistant = null;
        return false;
    }
}

public class NPCs
{
    public NPCs()
    {
        this.LabAssistants = new Dictionary<string, LabAssistant>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer CreateXmlSerializer()
    {
        // No need to cache this.
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NPCs));
        serializer.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(NPCs.XmlSerializer_LoadLabAssistants);
        return serializer;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, LabAssistant> LabAssistants { get; set; }

    public static void XmlSerializer_LoadLabAssistants(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
        var element = e.Element;

        if (obj is NPCs)
        {
            var npcs = (NPCs)obj;
            string name;
            LabAssistant assistant;
            if (LabAssistant.TryDeserializeFromXml(element, out name, out assistant))
                npcs.LabAssistants[name] = assistant;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following helper methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        return xmlString.LoadFromXML<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serial)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = serial.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)result;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Having done this, you now have a dictionary of lab assistants by name.

While this code will deserialize your data correctly, it won't reserialize it.  Custom code to serialize the dictionary would be required.

One final note - `XmlSerializer` will choke on the XML you provided because it [*requires* that Boolean values be in lowercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.toboolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Thus the following will throw an exception:

```
              <Correct>False</Correct>
```

If you did not mistype the XML and it really contains Booleans in this format, you will need to manually handle these fields.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i figured it out

Comment: Oh yeah, and thanks for that lower case boolean value!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create `QuestionCollection` class to hold the array of questions (having `typeof(Question[])` throws `<TagName xmlns="> was not expected`, probably because the deserializer is not smart enough).

What i do next is first reading to tag LabAssistant or any tag name, next reading to its child Questions tag and after that i deserialize the questions into `QuestionCollection`, so with `ReadToDescendant` I can access any child elements of the `NPCs`

```
        String questionsPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/questions.xml";
        XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(questionsPath));

        reader.ReadToDescendant("LabAssistant");
        reader.ReadToDescendant("Questions");

        XmlSerializer se = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionCollection));
        QuestionCollection qc=(QuestionCollection)se.Deserialize(reader);
```

**QuestionCollection** class:

```
[XmlType("Questions")]
public class QuestionCollection
{
    [XmlElement("Question")]
    public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
    public QuestionCollection() { }
}
```

**Question** class

```
[XmlType("Question")]
public class Question
{
    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public String Text { get;  set; }

    [XmlArray("Answers")]
    public Answer[] Answers { get;  set; }

    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public QuestionType Type { get;  set; }

    [XmlElement("Points")]
    public int Points { get; set; }

    public Question() { }
}
```

**Answer** class:

```
[XmlType("Answer")]
public class Answer
{
    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public String Text { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Correct")]
    public bool Correct { get; set; }

    public Answer() { }
}
```